# How to make checked a checkbox which is in closed modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, modal-dialog

I have this modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="column-settings-modal" tabindex="-1" role="basic" aria-hidden="false">
```

And this checkbox in the modal :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="partcountry-cb" value="Ülke"/>  &nbsp; Ülke <br />
```

I have a function to load modal. And I want to check this checkbox while modal is opening. My function is below :

```
function load_column_filters(surveyId,toShow) {

    var $modal = $('#column-settings-modal');
        $modal.modal();
        $("#partcountry-cb").attr("checked", true); 
}
```

However, the last statement does not work. (I have tried `.prop`,but it did not work.) Is this problem about modal itself or am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$("#partcountry-cb").prop("checked", true)` should do it, but since you've tried it and *"it didn't work"*, you should provide MCVE

Comment: Sorry, I am beginner in stackoverflow. .prob does not give any error. When I clicked the button which calls the function, it opens the modal but the checkbox is not checked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap modal? If yes, try check out this event [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) for modal. Try modified it content when it completely open by triggering shown callback like so :

```
function load_column_filters(surveyId,toShow) {

  var $modal = $('#column-settings-modal');
      $modal.modal();

}

$('#column-settings-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
   $("#partcountry-cb").prop("checked", true); 
});
```

Comment: Yes I am using bootstrap. I did as you write and i find out that it returns true when I check like (this).checked. However  it does not put a sign in the box.

Comment: are you using icheck plugin for checkbox? or any plugin for that UI?